# Retrofit 2 "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have ever looking for this problem on others posts, but I can't resolve it with them.

Format JSON response :

```
{  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "name":"Top fluide doubl\u00e9",
         "description":"DESCRIPTION ........"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Sweat avec fentes lat\u00e9rales",
         "description":"DESCRIPTION ........"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Robe \u00e9paules d\u00e9nud\u00e9es",
         "description":"DESCRIPTION ........"
      },
      {  
         "name":"Blouson bomber \u00e0 zip imprim\u00e9",
         "description":"DESCRIPTION ........"
      }
   ],
   "success":4
}
```

API for Retrofit 2

```
@GET("products")
    Call<List<ProductTest>> getProductList();

@GET("products/{product}")
Call<ProductTest> getProduct(@Path("product") int product);

@GET("success")
Call<SuccessTest> getSuccessNb();
```

JAVA Product Class

```
public class ProductTest {
    String name;
    String description;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Retrofit 2 builder

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:80/App/PHP_script/reading_all_products.php/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
CatalogAPI service = retrofit.create(CatalogAPI.class);
```

*Service that is working to get the success of the JSON response*

```
service.getSuccessNb().enqueue(new Callback<SuccessTest>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SuccessTest> call, Response<SuccessTest> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "" + response.body().getSuccess());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "NULL BODY -> " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SuccessTest> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("retrofit : ", "onFailure -> " + t.getLocalizedMessage());

            }
        });
```

Service that doesn't working to get the list of products or one product in the list

```
service.getProductList().enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductTest>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductTest>> call, Response<List<ProductTest>> response) {
                Log.i("retrofit : ", "pre-ok");

                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "NULL BODY -> " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductTest>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("retrofit : ", "onFailure -> " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

       service.getProduct(2).enqueue(new Callback<ProductTest>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProductTest> call, Response<ProductTest> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "" + response.message());
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", response.body().getName() + " => " + response.body().getDescription());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.i("retrofit : ", "NULL BODY -> " + response.errorBody());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProductTest> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("retrofit : ", "onFailure -> " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
```

An error is displayed for this two last cases :

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.

I have used a wrapper class that is working perfectly but I want some explanation for this cases in order to understand perfectly the communication between Retrofit 2 and JSON

Answer (score 0):

The incoming json

```
{  <- indicates its a object
   "products":[  <- this object has a field called products and its value is array
```

indicating there is object with one of field as products and this field is a list.

```
class ProductsResponse {
List<Products> products;
```

Comment: check the updates .. hope this helps you understand the json format

Comment: Many thanks, but how I can get only one object of the array "products" with retrofit ?